# Write a list that contains headings and data to a CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am currently writing a small Python 3.6 script that takes a CSV file and extracts a CVE and the hosts affected storing it in a list, as shown below.

```
CVE-2009-1234
10.11.1.1:80
10.11.1.3:80
10.11.1.4:80
10.11.1.2:80
10.11.1.22:80
10.11.1.2:80
10.11.1.27:80
10.11.1.23:80
10.11.1.29:80
10.11.1.228:80
CVE-2015-1234
10.11.1.224:443
10.11.1.224:80
10.11.1.74:8080
CVE-2015-1235
10.11.1.22
CVE-2017-1234
10.11.1.22:443
10.11.1.22:80
10.11.1.73:8080
CVE-2009-1235
10.11.1.22:443
10.11.1.22:80
```

However I am having trouble writing this data to a CSV file so each CVE and it's affected hosts are in seperate columns for example:

```
CVE-2009-1234    | CVE-2015-1234      | ... |
-----------------+--------------------+-----+
10.11.1.1:80     | 10.11.1.224:443    |     |
10.11.1.3:80     | 10.11.1.224:80     |     |
10.11.1.4:80     | 10.11.1.74:8080    |     |
10.11.1.2:80     |                    |     |
10.11.1.22:80    |                    |     |
10.11.1.2:80     |                    |     |
10.11.1.22:80    |                    |     |
10.11.1.23:80    |                    |     |
10.11.1.29:80    |                    |     |
10.11.1.228:80   |                    |     |
```

I originally thought that if I initialised a list the same size as the number of CVE's - then did an index lookup on the CVE number I could place each host into its corresponding index in the new list - however this became difficult when I had to try to initialise a new row because the previous spot had been filled.

I also looked into wether or not the CSV library has insert column functionality (which is obviously doesn't for good reason.

My working code is as follows:

```
import csv

filename = 'report.csv'
cve = set()

data = []

with open(filename) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        if ',' in row[11]:
            multi_cve = row[11].split(', ')
            for entry in multi_cve:
                cve.add(entry)
        else:
            cve.add(row[11])

    csvfile.seek(0)

    for uniq_cve in cve:
        data.append(uniq_cve)
        for row in reader:
            if row[2] == '':
                full_address = row[0]
            else:
                full_address = row[0] + ':' + row[2]

            if ',' in row[11]:
                multi_cve = row[11].split(', ')
                for entry in multi_cve:
                    if uniq_cve == entry:
                        data.append(full_address)
            else:
                if uniq_cve == row[11]:
                    data.append(full_address)
        csvfile.seek(0)

for entry in data:
    print(entry)
```

Forgot to add an example of the CSV:

```
IP,Hostname,Port,Port Protocol,CVSS,Severity,Solution Type,NVT Name,Summary,Specific Result,NVT OID,CVEs,Task ID,Task Name,Timestamp,Result ID,Impact,Solution,Affected Software/OS,Vulnerability Insight,Vulnerability Detection Method,Product Detection Result,BIDs,CERTs,Other References
10.11.1.1,,80,tcp,5,Medium,VendorFix,IIS Service Pack - 404,Ensure that the server is running the latest stable Service Pack,The remote IIS server *seems* to be Microsoft IIS 6.0 - w2k3 build 3790,1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.11874,NOCVE,80e72026-6304-4d23-8cdf-e4789507d231,Scan of all pinged hosts,2017-11-14T05:19:39Z,8a3d71d2-6fa4-4f06-ab7f-b8965667c56b,,"The Patch level (Service Pack) of the remote IIS server appears to be lower
  than the current IIS service pack level. As each service pack typically
  contains many security patches, the server may be at risk.

  Caveat: This test makes assumptions of the remote patch level based on static
  return values (Content-Length) within the IIS Servers 404 error message.
  As such, the test can not be totally reliable and should be manually confirmed.",,,"
Details:
IIS Service Pack - 404
(OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.11874)
Version used: $Revision: 4703 $
",,,,
10.11.1.1,,80,tcp,5,Medium,VendorFix,IIS Service Pack - 404,Ensure that the server is running the latest stable Service Pack,The remote IIS server *seems* to be Microsoft IIS 6.0 - w2k3 build 3790,1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.11874,NOCVE,80e72026-6304-4d23-8cdf-e4789507d231,Scan of all pinged hosts,2017-11-14T05:19:39Z,2ba7442c-5a46-4628-95d3-a2decae3a57a,,"The Patch level (Service Pack) of the remote IIS server appears to be lower
  than the current IIS service pack level. As each service pack typically
  contains many security patches, the server may be at risk.

  Caveat: This test makes assumptions of the remote patch level based on static
  return values (Content-Length) within the IIS Servers 404 error message.
  As such, the test can not be totally reliable and should be manually confirmed.",,,"
Details:
IIS Service Pack - 404
(OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.11874)
Version used: $Revision: 4703 $
",,,,
10.11.1.1,,80,tcp,4.3,Medium,VendorFix,Adobe BlazeDS XML and XML External Entity Injection Vulnerabilities,Adobe BlazeDS is prone to an XML-injection vulnerability and an XML External Entity injection vulnerability.,Vulnerable url: http://10.11.1.10/flex2gateway/http,1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.105211,CVE-2009-3960,80e72026-6304-4d23-8cdf-e4789507d231,Scan of all pinged hosts,2017-11-14T05:19:39Z,0a09cb06-7ae6-4234-90f3-bb61f10da46a,Attackers can exploit these issues to obtain sensitive information and carry out other attacks.,"Updates are available, please refer to the linked advisory.","The following applications are affected:

 BlazeDS 3.2 and earlier versions
 LiveCycle 9.0, 8.2.1, and 8.0.1
 LiveCycle Data Services 3.0, 2.6.1, and 2.5.1
 Flex Data Services 2.0.1
 ColdFusion 9.0, 8.0.1, 8.0, and 7.0.2",,"Send an modificated GET request and check the response
Details:
Adobe BlazeDS XML and XML External Entity Injection Vulnerabilities
(OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.105211)
Version used: $Revision: 7293 $
",,38197,,"http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/38197, http://www.adobe.com/support/security/bulletins/apsb10-05.html"
```

Comment: What does your csv file look like?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example of the CSV

Comment: It looks like you have commas in other random places in this file. i.e. `ColdFusion 9.0, 8.0.1, 8.0, and 7.0.2"`. Do you have a choice in the delimiter of the file, or is that just what you're given?

Comment: I had a look at the OpenVAS settings and it doesn't look like I could specify a custom delimiter. Having a look at contents of the reader it doesn't seem to interpret the commas in the other places.

Comment: `"Successful exploitation will allow remote\n  attacker to downgrade the security of a session to use 'RSA_EXPORT' cipher suites,\n  which are significantly weaker than non-export cipher suites. This may allow a\n  man-in-the-middle attacker to more easily break the encryption and monitor\n  or tamper with the encrypted stream.\n\n  Impact Level: Application"` has extra commas in the string but doesn't cause erroneous parsing

Comment: The csv file is ok (quoted multiline fields).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a solution in the end. It may not be the best solution, but it works for my purposes. What I did:

- Instead of inserting everything into the one list I created a list of
  lists **cve_lists**
- I then find the longest list in **cve_lists** - which tells us how many rows we need at a minimum

The code is as follows:

```
longest_list = len(max(cve_lists,key=len))

rows = []
row = []

# works out the maximum number of iterations we need to get all entries
for count in range(0, (len(cve) * longest_list)):
    for entry in cve_lists:
        try:
            row.append(entry[0])
            entry.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            # if there is no index, we know there is no data and 
            # append a blank entry
            row.append('')

    rows.append(row)
    row = []

with open(args.file , 'w') as resultFile:
    wr = csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerows(rows)
```